# Anime about a little girl who lives in a cabin by herself in the middle of the forest/woods

Tags: binchou-tan

I remember watching it in the early 2000s. The style was unique. It barely had any dialogue (the girl doesn't speak at all since she is little), only narration since I think it was a kid show. I think her grandma/parents who raised her in the cabin passed away, so she lived by herself and was really young. She would go outside with a hat on and find stuff like water, and explored many areas in the forest. I remember a scene where something was shaken and a snake appeared. And the narration told us that she was afraid of snakes so she stood very still until it moved away. I think later on, in the next episode or so, she met new friends and they were all little girls. I also think it was an OVA? I really want to see it again.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds a lot like [Binchou-tan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binch%C5%8D-tan_%28manga%29), though it looks like a children's show, there's some pretty heavy moments in the show.

[image]

She lives in a cabin out in the forest by herself. It's hinted at that she used to live in the cabin with her grandparents and they've died (she visits a tree like it's a grave). She also wears a piece of charcoal on her head, that's sort of a play on words with her name (binchou=charcoal). I think in the very first episode, she encounters the snake. Although she does speak, a lot of the anime is narrated by a woman. Every once in a while, a bunch of her friends (all girls, sometimes animals) come to visit her, but for the most part, she is completely alone.

It's about 12 episodes long at about 12 minutes per episode and was adapted from a 4-koma manga.

More info:

- [My Anime List](http://myanimelist.net/anime/750/Binchou-tan)
- [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=5314)

Comment: Snake scene is indeed [in the first episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gzHbrFqKlY&t=478)